# Postgresql Left join show null values if there is not in condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say i have a table like this

hr_employee

```
id     name
1    'emp A'
2    'emp B'
3    'emp C'
```

sale_order

```
id    name      employee_id     date_order
1   'ORD/01'      1            '2021-07-07'
2   'ORD/02'      2            '2021-08-02'
3   'ORD/03'      3            '2021-08-17'
4   'ORD/04'      3            '2021-08-18'
```

im using this query:

```
SELECT 
string_agg(s.id::varchar,',') sale_ids,
e.name

from hr_employee e
left join sale_order s on s.employee_id = e.id
where s.date_order between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31'

group by e.name
```

and this is the output

```
sale_ids  name
 2        Emp B
 4,3      Emp C
```

i want to have output like this:

```
sale_ids  name
          Emp A
 2        Emp B
 4,3      Emp C
```

my question is how can i make Emp A appear but shows null in sale_ids fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the criteria on the `date_order` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the left join:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(s.id::varchar, ',') sale_ids, e.name
FROM hr_employee e
LEFT JOIN sale_order s
    ON s.employee_id = e.id AND
       s.date_order >= '2021-08-01' AND s.date_order < '2021-09-01'
GROUP BY e.name;
```

The `WHERE` condition is (logically) *after* the `FROM` clause, so the NULL values added by the left join can be eliminated. The `ON` clause, on the other hand, is part of the join and cannot exclude rows from `hr_employee`.

Answer (score 1):

Filtered out by "date_order",Try to change to "between '2021-07-01' and '2021-08-31'"

Answer (score -1):

For employers who hasn't sales between '2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31' the field "s.date_order" has NULL value. So this employers is fitlred by WHERE clause.

```sql
SELECT 
string_agg(s.id::varchar,',') sale_ids,
e.name

from hr_employee e
left join sale_order s on s.employee_id = e.id
where s.date_order between ('2021-08-01' and '2021-08-31') OR NULL

group by e.name
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.